# Get content length of incoming HttpListenerRequest input stream

Tags: c#, .net, binary-data, httplistener, httplistenerrequest

I am making a server using C#'s `HttpListner`, and the server is handling incoming binary data from incoming post requests. I am trying to make the post request handler, and because I am handling binary data I am using `byte[]` (which is the buffer I am reading to). But the issue is I have to supply the length of the buffer before reading anything to the buffer. I tried `HttpListnerRequest.InputStream.Length`, but it throws this:

```
System.NotSupportedException: This stream does not support seek operations.
```

Is there another way to get the length of the stream? Other answers to similar questions just use `StreamReader`, but StreamReader does not do binary.

Here is my code that throws the error.

```
// If the request is a post request and the request has a body
Stream input = request.InputStream; // "request" in this case is the HttpListnerRequest
byte[] buffer = new byte[input.Length]; // Throws System.NotSupportedException.
input.Read(buffer, 0, input.Length);
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just copy it into a `MemoryStream` with `CopyToAsync`?  A lot less error prone.

Comment: For large request bodies, that would take a lot of memory. I don't have that much RAM.

Comment: Well, neither your question nor your answer considers that point.  Where are you putting it?  A file?  `FileStream` and `CopyToAsync` applies equally well for that scenario.

Comment: Also, in your answer you declare a byte array whose length is equal to the entire request length, so if you don't have enough RAM, your proposed solution won't work either.

Comment: What do you plan on doing with `buffer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HttpListnerRequest.ContentLength64`, which represents the length of the request body, which in this case is the input stream. Example:

```
// If the request is a post request and the request has a body
long longLength = request.ContentLength64;
int length = (int) longLength;
Stream input = request.InputStream; // "request" in this case is the HttpListnerRequest
byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
input.Read(buffer, 0, length);
```